# Having trouble printing the information from an array, can't figure out how to run through the array that was stored in a class?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, for-loop, printing

Main function and class definitions.
    #include 
    #include

```
using namespace std;

class gameobject
{
    public:
        void set_id_num(int num);
        int get_id_num();
        void set_name(string name1);
        string get_name();
        void set_type(int type_of_game);
        string get_type();
        void set_buy_value(float buy_game);
        float get_buy_value();
        void set_market_value(float market_price);
        float get_market_value();
        void set_year(int year1);
        int get_year();

    private:
        int id_num;//identifier number for the game
        string name;//the name of the game
        int type;//whether the game is cartridge, CD, DVD, BR, download
        string type_name;//type of game
        float buy_value;//price of game
        float market_value;//value of game
        int year;//year the game was made
};

class gamelist
{
private:
    int gamecounter = 0;
    gameobject gameobjects[10];

public:
    void add_game();
    void print_list();
    float total_value();
};

int main()
{
    int option;//menu choice

    do
    {
        //menu
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please choose an option from the below menu. " << endl;
        cout << "1. Add Game" << endl;
        cout << "2. Print List" << endl;
        cout << "3. Total value of collection" << endl;
        cout << "4. Delete Game" << endl;
        cout << "5. Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Which would you like to execute? ";
        cin >> option;
        cin.ignore();

        //to add the games
        if (option == 1)
        {
            gamelist run;

            run.add_game();//goes through the options for setting up a game
        }

        //print game info
        else if (option == 2)
        {
            gamelist run;

            run.print_list();
        }

        //total value
        else if (option == 3)
        {
            gamelist run;

            run.total_value();
        }

    } while (option != 5);

    if (option == 5)
        return 0;
}
```

The area I am having issues in.

```
//adds the inputted market value in the array
float gamelist::total_value()
{
    float value_of_games = 0;

    cout << "The value of the games is: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < gamecounter; i++)
    {
        value_of_games = gameobjects[i].get_market_value() + value_of_games;
    }

    return(value_of_games);
}
//prints the info in the array
void gamelist::print_list()
{
    cout << "The game information is listed below: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < gamecounter; i++)
    {
        cout << gameobjects[i].get_id_num() << endl;
        cout << gameobjects[i].get_name() << endl;
        cout << gameobjects[i].get_type() << endl;
        cout << gameobjects[i].get_buy_value() << endl;
        cout << gameobjects[i].get_market_value() << endl;
        cout << gameobjects[i].get_year() << endl;
    }
}
//to add a game to the lise
void gamelist::add_game()
{
    gamecounter++;

    if (gamecounter > 10)
    {
        cout << "You cannot add any more games. ";
    }

    else
    {
        int id;
        string name_game;
        int type_game;
        int buy;
        int market;
        int year_game;

        cout << "Please enter an id number for the game: ";
        cin >> id;

        cout << "Please enter a name for the game: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, name_game);

        cout << "There are four types of games." << endl;
        cout << "     0. Cartridge " << endl;
        cout << "     1. CD " << endl;
        cout << "     2. DVD " << endl;
        cout << "     3. BR " << endl;
        cout << "     4. Download " << endl;

        cout << "Which type do you want to set for the game (enter number)? ";
        cin >> type_game;

        cout << "Please set a buying value for the game: ";
        cin >> buy;

        cout << "Please set the market value of the game: ";
        cin >> market;

        cout << "What is the model year of the game? ";
        cin >> year_game;


        for (; gamecounter < 10; gamecounter++)
        {
            gameobjects[gamecounter].set_id_num(id);//passes value
            gameobjects[gamecounter].set_id_num(id);//passes value
            gameobjects[gamecounter].set_name(name_game);//passes value
            gameobjects[gamecounter].set_type(type_game);//passes value
            gameobjects[gamecounter].set_buy_value(buy);//passes value
            gameobjects[gamecounter].set_market_value(market);//passes value
            gameobjects[gamecounter].set_year(year_game);//passes value
        }
    }
}
```

The set and get functions.

```
//sets id num for the game
void gameobject::set_id_num(int num)
{
    id_num = num;
}

//displays the id num for the game
int gameobject::get_id_num()
{
    return(id_num);
}

//sets desired name for game
void gameobject::set_name(string name1)
{
    name = name1;
}

//displays the name of the game
string gameobject::get_name()
{
    return(name);
}

//presents a menu to choose type of game
void gameobject::set_type(int type_of_game)
{
    type = type_of_game;
}

//prints the type of game chosen
string gameobject::get_type()
{
    if (type == 0)
    {
        type_name = "cartridge";
        return(type_name);
    }
    else if (type == 1)
    {
        type_name = "CD";
        return(type_name);
    }
    else if (type == 2)
    {
        type_name = "DVD";
        return(type_name);
    }
    else if (type == 3)
    {
        type_name = "BR";
        return(type_name);
    }
    else if (type == 4)
    {
        type_name = "download";
        return(type_name);
    }
}

//sets the buying value of game
void gameobject::set_buy_value(float buy_game)
{
    buy_value = buy_game;
}

//displays the buying value for game
float gameobject::get_buy_value()
{
    return(buy_value);
}

//sets market value
void gameobject::set_market_value(float market_price)
{
    market_value = market_price;
}

//displays market value
float gameobject::get_market_value()
{
    return(market_value);
}

//sets model year of the game
void gameobject::set_year(int year1)
{
    year = year1;
}

//displays model year
int gameobject::get_year()
{
    return(year);
}
```

My question is, how do I count the number of games added? Because the way I am doing it is not working.

How can I change the print function so it actually prints something? My code is not write there but after some research I really don't know why it doesn't work.

Lastly, I am totally stumped on adding the market values from each game to get the total value. This is the total_value function. I gave it a try but there are some bugs there too.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: first use a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to hold your `gameobject`s and you can just use the `size()` function to get how many are in the vector.

Comment: Use a `std::vector` to store your `gameobject`s, then you'll be able to use `.push_back()` to add new `gameobject` instances and `.size()` to see how many you've added. Then you need to make sure that the `gamelist` that you are adding these to exists for the entire time you wish to use it. The way you do it now is you create one, you add something to it, then you delete it so it's gone... then you create another one to add to it or print from it, and delete that one... etc etc. If you declare it in a set of brackets, even in an `if` statement body, it's deleted when you leave that section

Comment: `how do I count the number of games added?` Isn't that what `gamecounter` is for? Only you are messing it up in `add_game`- why on earth are you running a loop there?

Comment: @igor tandetnik i had to store the info in an array so I ran a for loop that stores the information in one index

Comment: How am I messing it up i am not sure I know what you mean?

Comment: @ryanp I have never used vectors before so I dont really know what any of that means, could you clarify? also how to I ensure the gamelist is active the entire time? should I use the same instances in each if statement?

Comment: @AmandaGenise It looks like you want to use it for the entire main() section, so I'd declare/define it in main. Then you can just reference it in your if statements. One of the answers has the syntax for that.

Comment: "I ran a for loop that stores the information in one index" - no, it stores the information in every single index from 1 through 10. You fill all objects in the array with the same data. You don't need a loop if you want to write to just one object.

Comment: @AmandaGenise Also, and this is more a personal preference, but sometimes when you have classes who's member functions do a lot of cout/cin, that class becomes less focused. Now instead of managing gameobjects, it's also interacting with the user. I would do my cout/cin in your main function, in the if statement, then have it pass the user input to a function of gamelist, which then instantiates a new gameobject using the input that it was passed, and pushes it onto it's own internal vector.

Comment: @igortandetnik so if I run the addgame function it will store it in an index? then if I run it again it will store the new info in another index in the array

Comment: @ryanp thanks I will take that into consideration!!

Comment: thank you everyone for the help it finally worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need to declare `gamelist` object not locally (every time in `if (option == ...)` scope) but globally: e.g., after the header of `main`:

```
int main() {
    //declare you gamelist object here
    gamelist run;
    ...
}
```

This way the `gamelist` object would preserve between user inputs and store the information.

2) `addGame()` should add only one game and the loop line is not needed: `for (; gamecounter < 10; gamecounter++)`
Incrementing the counter `gamecounter++` should be done at the end of `addGame()` function.

Comment: so how do I store in an index of the array without using a for loop @john_west

Comment: You store your index in `gamecounter` variable. You add one element at a time - with number `gamecounter` (which takes values from 0 to 9), see also `Richard Hodges` answer. Also, if incrementing the counter at the end of `addGame()`, the condition would be `if (gamecounter > 9)`

Answer (score 1):

c++ arrays are indexed from 0. When you add the first game it needs to go at index 0, which means you must increment `gamecounter` *after* you have entered the game details into the game array.

`gamecounter` can be thought of as two things:

1. The number of games in the array now
2. The index where the *next* game will go (not the index of the last game in the array)

If you work this way then `gamecounter` will represent the number of games correctly.

Of course I will not be the first here to tell you to use a std::vector to store your games. then you can do this:

add a game:

```
gameobject go(...parameters...);
go.set...();
gameobjects.push_back(std::move(go));
```

get the number of games:

```
return gameobjects.size();
```

iterate all games:

```
for(const auto& game : gameobjects) {
  // do what you need to do on game
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use vector to hold the game object or you can use a static member variable to hold the number of game objects you created.

For vector:
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm

For static member :
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/